# Spring Hibernate eats exceptions

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

With `@Transaction` and with trace level logging of Spring I see that Hibernate has an exception on a db constraint but it just rolls back the transaction. I tried using `@Exception` without success to try to catch it.

I see a suggestion online to use Spring AOP `@AfterThrowing` to catch such events.

This seems like a rather complex way to handle a commonplace event. It seems so much easier with try/catch and old fashioned commits/rollbacks. Is there no better way 
in Spring Hibernate?

I'm processing XML messages from a queue. Depending on the type of the exception I get I might want to just catch it and put the bad incoming queue message into an db error table and continue the transaction. (If I just blindly rollback the message will get put back on the queue which might be good in some cases but not in others).

From what I've read there are ways of being made aware of some errors (for some reason not the constraint error) and logging them. Are there ways of interrupting the transaction after an exception and deciding if one wants to commit, continue or rollback?

If not, can one use old style commits and rollback with spring hibernate?

Comment: It's not eating the exception it's handling it. Eating would be catching and not doing a roll back.

Comment: By eating I mean not throwing another exception after processing. It's supposed to throw a Hibernate Runtime Exception (subclass of Exception) but when I use @Exception nothing gets caught. I would like to be aware of the exception and change processing based on its type.

Comment: They seem to have gone for a notification model. I personally wouldn't be comfortable with "there was an exception so I rolled back". The spilt milk has been swept under the rug at that point as it were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure `SimpleMappingException` resolver and log the exception there:

```
public class MyExceptionResolver extends SimpleMappingExceptionResolver {
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyExceptionResolver .class);

@Override
protected void logException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.logger.warn(buildLogMessage(ex, request), ex);
}

<bean class="com.mypackage.MyExceptionResolver"/>
```

**EDIT:**

You can choose to do anything. The above class has nothing to do with rolling back. It's useful to intercept exceptions and do whatever you want with them.
By default, Spring rolls back for any `RuntimeException`.
If you want to configure rollback policy:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { CustomException.class})
```

or

```
@Transactional(noRollBackFor= { CustomException.class})
```

Comment: Thanks but I'd also like to decide to commit or rollback; not just log the exception.

Comment: Thanks that should do it.